# How to get $db_host as domain from Juju?

Tags: juju

I'm using a manual enviroment with Juju, and to not lose the machines I've added them all as machinename.local (using avahi-discover). It's not possible to use static ips because of some rules from administration.

When I add a relation between a service and a mysql, for example, the $db_host always gets the ip and not the domain from mysql host.

How do I make relations with $db_host as an avahi domain instead of an IP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, a few things to understand about relations:

- Juju doesn't have much to do with deciding particular relation settings (eg. a choice between IP address or domain name). It is up to charms implementing a particular relation type to decide what relation data to set.
- As an exception, Juju does set the `private-address` relation setting by default for convenience, but charms can delete or change it.
- Juju provides `private-address` in the relation setting as well as the output of `unit-get private-address` as an address, not a name.

So, that you're ending up with an IP address and not a hostname is a function of both the charm that you're relating to and Juju's defaults, depending on the case.

Looking at the mysql charm, I see that it sets `host` (in `hooks/db-relation-joined`) based on the output of `unit-get private-address`.

So, one option is to modify each charm where it sets the address, and change it to supply the name you need instead. Or where charms just use the default `private-address` setting, to override it in the `*-relation-joined` hooks. In your environment using something like a call to `hostname` and appending `.local` would do. But this is clearly not a great solution, since you have to modify every charm affected.

Unfortunately, most charms are designed for environments that work the other way round - where IPs generally don't change (or an administrator has control to make sure that they don't), but mDNS (as needed for Zeroconf) generally doesn't work, and there's no central DNS server available. So although Juju doesn't particularly mandate charms to support addresses only, this is generally what the charms in the charm store all do.